# Global event handler to capture click-like events, beyond actual mouse clicks (e.g. tabindex keyboard navigation, accessibility API 'clicks')

Tags: javascript, accessibility

If I have some clickable html elements in a page, like:

```
<a>link</a>
<button>button</button>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

and I have a global function that I want to have called whenever someone "clicks" on them:

```
const handleElementActivated = (event) => {
  console.log('now handling an interaction with element', event);
}
```

But I don't want to just handle mouse clicks - I also want this handler to be called for other click-like activations of these UI elements. E.g.:

- Hitting the enter key to activate a focused (tabindex) element.
- A screen reader triggering the element via the accessibility API.

How can I cover all such events with a global event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SCR35: Making actions keyboard accessible by using the onclick event of anchors and buttons](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR35.html#SCR35-description) says:

> While "onclick" sounds like it is tied to the mouse, the onclick event is actually mapped to the default action of a link or button. The default action occurs when the user clicks the element with a mouse, but it also occurs when the user focuses the element and hits enter or space, and when the element is triggered via the accessibility API.

It does not specifically mention 'click' event listeners, but in my testing I have found that `window.addEventListener('click'...` does seem to behave like "onclick", so also fires when the user hits space/enter on a focused element or triggers it via the accessibility API:

```
window.addEventListener(
  'click',
  handleElementActivated,
  true // in most cases you also probably want to set useCapture to true
);
```

However, I haven't found whether this non-mouse-click event handler triggering is documented in the web standards somewhere (someone please edit this response if you know).